# AutoComplete - yii

Tags: yii

I am trying to add a field with auto complete functionality , I have used javascript for this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css " />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js "></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js "></script>
 <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        function split( val ) {
            //document.write(val.length);
            return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            //echo (term.length);
            //document.write(term.length);
            return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $( "#Tag_tag_name" )
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                var a=0;
//                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB)
//                    {
//                       a=a+1; 
//                    }
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                }
//                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.P)
//                    {
//                        alert(a);
//                    }


            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                },
                focus: function() {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var terms = split( this.value );
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push( ui.item.value );
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push( "" );
                    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                    return false;
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Now What I want tot do is instead of this static values in AvaialbleTags variable I want values from database ? Plus I want to limit three values to be add by the user.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: have you tried CJuiComplete? combine that with an action in the controller that queries the db for you values, and you have this functionality. there are many tutorial wikis also about this.

Comment: No I have not tried CJuiComplete

Comment: anyone can hlp me to modify it ?

Comment: what's your current form code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i am using [multicomplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multicomplete/)

```
    $this->widget('ext.widgets.MultiComplete', array(
              'model'=>$model,
              'attribute'=>$attribute,
              'splitter'=>',',
              'sourceUrl'=>$this->createUrl($url),
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
              'options'=>array(
                      'minLength'=>'1',
    ),
              'htmlOptions'=>array(
                      'size'=>'60'
                      ),
                      ));
```